# Library for reading HCCB (Microsoft Tag) barcodes?

Tags: barcode, microsoft-tag

Recently I've noticed many [HCCB](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/High_Capacity_Color_Barcode) ([Microsoft Tag](http://www.gettag.mobi/)) barcodes, which Zxing does not recognize. Is there any free or open-source reader library to read these codes?

If there is not any software to do this, what would be the best method to recognize the triangles or dots in this type of code?

Answer (score 2):

No, currently the Microsoft Tag Reader and Bing Vision are the only apps that can read Microsoft Tags.

According to the Microsoft Research site on [High Capacity Color Barcodes (HCCB)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/hccb/default.aspx), [Gavin Jancke](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/gavinj/default.aspx) is the original inventor - maybe you could try and contact him directly? :)

Comment: The bottom of that page has listed some patents for the method of encoding data to HCCB. Perhaps the reason there are no other readers is because it is Microsoft patented? http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/gavinj/default.aspx#PersonalResearchProjects

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. There's been some speculation, and even hints from the M$ Tag Team, that Microsoft will release a API for integrating tags directly in your own software. But at this time there's nothing concrete, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft now makes available the "Microsoft Tag Scanning SDK". I believe it is free as in beer.

http://tag.microsoft.com/developer/scanning-sdk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/canadaduane/elm-hccb an implementation of HCCB in [ELM](http://elm-lang.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into JAB Code. It has online decoder, smartphone decoder. It's hccb and open source

More on this [here](https://hvitis.dev/jab-code-and-everything-you-need-to-know-about-color-bar-code)